# How to typecheck a string against an object type after json parse

Tags: json, typescript, websocket

I have some types:

```
export type Ping = {
  kind: 'ping',
  lag?: number
}

export type Message = {
  kind: 'message',
  value: string
}
```

I have an incoming message string encoded json:

```
let msg = "{kind:'message', value: 3 }",
    ping = "{kind:'ping'}";`;
```

After I convert this into an object:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(msg);
```

I want to validate these messages to have the expected properties and dispatch them like so:

```
export function isMessage(_: any): _ is Message {
  if (typeof _ === 'object') {
    let res = (_ as Message);
    if (res.kind === 'message' && res.value && typeof res.value === 'string') {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


export function use(_: any) {
  if (isMessage(_)) {
    console.log('Message: ', _.value);
  }
}
```

Do I have to typecheck every field of every kind of message like above, or is there an simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpler, or at least cleaner, way is to write a [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) and run your data through a validator like [ajv](https://ajv.js.org). Here's how your `Message` type could be validated:

```
import Ajv, { JSONSchemaType } from 'ajv';
const ajv = new Ajv();

export interface Message {
  kind: 'message',
  value: string
}

const messageSchema: JSONSchemaType<Message> = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    kind: { type: 'string', const: 'message' },
    value: { type: 'string' }
  },
  required: ['kind', 'value'],
  additionalProperties: false
};

const isMessage = ajv.compile(messageSchema);
export { isMessage };
```

Comment: Although I accept this, I would switch to a real typed language instead if I ever need this. I will hardcode stuff for now.

Comment: @eguneys Hardcoding certainly works too! Just to be clear, though, functions returned by `ajv.compile` are type guards (their return type is like your `_ is Message`), so they perform the exact same job.